# How to pass an Image in SFML C++

Tags: c++, image, sfml

I am trying to make a simple function or class that selects an image and returns it or passes it in some way to a different class. Is it as simple as knowing what type the Image is considered? or do I need to do something else? I am running Code::Blocks 10.05 with GNU GCC compiler on a windows 8 computer. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks to Aesthete, I made some progress. Now I have this:

```
class Background{
    sf::Image BGI;
    sf::Sprite BG;
    Image& img;

    public:
    void rimage(std::string name){
        sf::Image extra;
        extra.LoadFromFile(name);
        img = extra;
    }
    void init(std::string name){
    BGI = img
    BG.SetPosition(0.f,0.f);
    BG.SetImage(BGI);

    }
};
```

But when I run it, I get this:

```
 ...4 error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Image" with no type
```

Also,

```
...10 error: 'img' is defined in this scope
```

I have included the libraries that I need to run SFML, I just left it out to keep things clean, I adjusted the lines the errors above occurred on to make it easier to follow.

Isn't img now sort of a global variable within Background?
and I thought `Image&` was the type of `img`... What needs to change here?

Comment: `Image& img` needs to be `sf::Image img`. Then just call `img.LoadFromFile(name);`

Comment: Ok sweet, one last thing, If I wanted to store this stuff in an array or a vector, what would I put the array/vector as and which variable should I save to the array/vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a `load` method, nor any extra `Image` objects. You can do all this processing in the constructor.

```
class Background{
  private:
    // You only need an image and a background, if that.
    sf::Image BGI;
    sf::Sprite BG;

  public:
    // Use a constructor.
    Background(std::string name)
    {
      SetBackground(name, Vector2f(0.f, 0.f));
    }
    void SetBackground(std::string name, sf::Vector2f pos)
    {
      BGI.LoadFromFile(name);
      BG.SetImage(BGI);
      BG.SetPosition(pos);
    }
};

// Constructor loads image, sets image to sprite, and set sprite position.
Background bg("MyBackground.png");

// You can change the background image an position like so.
bg.SetBackgrond("newImage.png", Vector2f(10.f, 20.f));
```

Comment: looks good, let me test that real quick, thanks for the fast reply!

Comment: I edited my question above because I wasn't sure how to add the code within the comments... And I just figured out how.

Comment: @user1429351 - I've completely changed the answer to match your updates.

Comment: Wish I could upvote this twice, it has really really helped me

Comment: @user1429351 - I made another change that will help you change backgrounds.